# How to get previous apk version code after updating app in android?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play

I want to get my **Previous App version code** of the app from which the user has updated to this updated version from the play store.

****E.g****

> I have an app with version codes 8,9,10. I want to know from which
> previous app code user has updated to this newer 10 app.

In simple words, I want to get track of previous version code in **onCreate()** method so I will display content accordingly.

Comment: you could just save the version of the app in your own database and then use it

Comment: ok this can be possible but I have already uploaded app. so is there any way to get their previous version code after they update the app to a newer version